# How to use babel's env preset to target Node with ES6 modules enabled?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, babel-preset-env

With this config:

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "16"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

...Babel converts `import`/`export` syntax to CommonJS (`require`).

**How do I change this** so Babel preserves `import` and `export` syntax, so I can run the resulting output as an ES module (e.g. running it with `node` with an `.mjs` extension)?

I've tried adding `"esmodules": true` to the `targets`, but this doesn't seem to make any difference when combined with `"node": "16"`.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: @rendom No. Did you upvote the question?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue. The best "solution" I came up with was to simply not use `preset-env` with the code. Since newer versions of Node basically support all the features that preset-env currently includes, I just didn't apply it, and I'll only apply plugins as needed for experimental solution.

Not a great solution for older versions of Node, but adequate for recent ones.